# jQuery >> Advice on how to parse, filter and sort XML data needed

Tags: xml, ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

What is the best starting point for parsing, filtering and sorting XML-data with jQuery, similar to XPath?

Background:
I'm new to jQuery and searching for this topic resulted in hundreds of different plugins and tutorials. However, i couldn't find a solution in the jQuery-API for filtering and sorting. Now, i'm really confused about the many different workarounds for a function, which i thought would be a core part of the ajax library?!

So, could you please share your opinions:
What is the best/standard way to go?
Should i use a plugin; if so, which one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck no need to use any plugins the methods to do this are built in the library

These links provide a good explanation on how to use them

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/